# PHPMailer, situación con Archivos Adjuntos

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy enviando un documento PDF con PHPMailer y funciona perfectamente, pero quiero agregar un Input File a mi formulario para enviar los 2 Attachments, es decir, recibir el PDF y el archivo que suba en Input File. Por alguna razón no estoy recibiendo el Input File.

Datos>
Utilizo Emailtrap para recibir los correos.

Input File de mi formulario tiene como name='foto',

Mi formulario comienza asi:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" method="post" id="bolsa" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formpdf.php" >...
```

Y mi archivo formpdf.php es:

```
    $file= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];

//Corriendo la funcion
sendEmail($pdf,$enquirydata);

//Function to send the information

function sendEmail($pdf,$enquirydata){

    $emailbody='';

    $emailbody .= '<h1>Email recibido de '. $enquirydata['Fnombre'].'</h1>';
    $emailbody .=' <h3>Ver documentos Adjuntos</h3>';

    //Para enviar el mensaje en el cuerpo
    // foreach ($enquirydata as $title=> $data){
    //     $emailbody .= '<strong>'. $title . '</strong>: '. $data . '<br />';
    // }

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'f4f540749a12b0';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '20097ae51199a2';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 2525;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('Test@example.com', 'PHPMailer');
    $mail->AddAddress('maguilar@verdehn.com', 'Solicitud Empleo');

    $mail->addStringAttachment($pdf, 'solicitud.pdf');
    $mail->addAttachment($file,$_FILES['foto']['name']);

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);      
    $mail->Subject = 'Enquiry from' . $enquirydata['Fnombre'];
    $mail->Body    =  $emailbody;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($emailbody);

    $mail->send();
    
    header('Location:index.php');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

}
```

Los errores que me muestra son:

1. Line 150 Undefined index: foto //alli esta el codigo $file= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
2. Line 150 Trying to access array offset on value of type null.
3. Line 187 Undefined variable: file //alli esta el codigo $mail->addAttachment($file,$_FILES['foto']['name']);
4. Line 187 Undefined index: foto
5. Line 187 Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Alguien me da una mano con este problema porfavor!

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola. No funciona: `$mail->addAttachment($file,$_FILES['foto']['name']);` El valor  $_FILES['foto']['name'] no contiene el nombre actual del archivo enviado por post. Dicho nombre se encuentra en $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] y apunta a su ubicación en el directorio temporal. No creo que desde allí la puedas enviar porque va a ser borrada por el colector de basura cuando se envíe la página. Debes usar ese valor para mover el archivo a una dirección permanente y desde ella enviarlo. Luego podrás borrarlo si no la necesitas.

Comment: @quevedo gracias por comentar a la publicación. honestamente no entiendo tu respuesta. Me ayudas a entender el porque me muestra los errores que muestro arriba y como podría resolverlo?

Comment: 1. Debes pasar la imagen recibida a una ubicación dentro de tu directorio público supongamos `$fotopath = '<directorio_publico>/img/nombre_para_la_imagen.extension'; move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $fotopath);` Quedará ubicada en $fotopath y desde allí si puedes anexarla

Comment: 2. Es necesario hacer algunas validaciones: que el archivo de imagen sea realmente tal, que su dimensión sea mayor que 0, porque la vas a reenviar y te cabe responsabilidad por lo que envías.

Comment: Aclaración al asunto de nombres: $_FILES['foto']['name'] contiene el nombre original del archivo de imagen. $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] contiene el nombre con que es subida **temporalmente** al servidor. Si no se hace algo con ella es borrada, por el colector de basura, cuando se envía la respuesta. Para guardarla y poderla usar, se debe asignar un nombre seguro y se mueve a un directorio adecuado. Usualmente el juego de nombres se guarda en una BD para usos futuros (incluido borrarla).

Comment: @quevedo no puedo establecer un directorio publico porque amigo, es un formulario publico que se rellena con algunos campos, esos datos los transformo en un PDF y lo mando por correo, en el mismo formulario tengo un Input tipo File que el usuario que no conozco yo, va a subir una imagen que no se si su extensión sera JPG o PNG y por ende no conozco su directorio.

Comment: si yo quiero mandar un archivo que tengo en mi pc por correo entonces si lo haria asi y creo que no tendria problemas, pero es una informacion que el cliente llenara a la hora de abrir el formulario.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111839/discussion-between-nor-and-quevedo).